# Typescript Generic Syntax < P extends U | undefined = undefined >

Tags: typescript, next-auth

I bumped to this definition when I was browsing Next-auth.js type definition.

```
export declare function signIn<P extends RedirectableProviderType | undefined = undefined>(provider?: LiteralUnion<BuiltInProviderType>, options?: SignInOptions, authorizationParams?: SignInAuthorizationParams): Promise<P extends RedirectableProviderType ? SignInResponse | undefined : undefined>;
```

What does `undefined = undefined` part of the definition mean?

Comment: you should read it like `P extends RedirectableProviderType | undefined` , the default value is `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`P extends RedirectableProviderType | undefined = undefined` means that `RedirectableProviderType` or `undefined` types are allowed to be asserted when invoking `signIn` (e.g. `signIn<RedirectableProviderType>`), however when no assertion type is provided - `P` will be defaulted to `undefined`.

This can alternatively be viewed as `P (extends RedirectableProviderType | undefined) = undefined`